# Listen to field's value change of MongoDB's document with Spring

Tags: java, spring, mongodb, rest

According to my use-case, whenever a user is registered to my site, the following document will be created in User collection.

```
{
 "_id": "xxxx",
 "name": "xxxx",
 "hash": "xxxx",
 "salt": "xxxx",
 "approved": false
}
```

Only after the admin's approval, the user's registration request will be accepted. The admin won't approve immediately after the registration and generally takes more than a day to look at the registration request list. After admin's approval, the above document changes like below: (approved field changes to true)

```
{
 "_id": "xxxx",
 "name": "xxxx",
 "hash": "xxxx",
 "salt": "xxxx",
 "approved": true
}
```

The below two functions are implemented with spring.

```
public void createRegistrationRequest(User obj) {
   // logic
}

public void executeAfterApproval() {
   // logic
}
```

The `executeAfterApproval()` method should execute when the *approved* field value changes to true. How to listen to this field's value change and trigger the method's execution with Spring?

PS: Actually, the original use-case is a bit difficult to explain as it is more related to internal scenarios. So, translated the scenario as user registration for an easy understanding of the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use MongoDB change streams. If you are using Spring Data it has support for both imperative and reactive drivers. You can use a change stream for listening to User collection changes and apply some criterias to be more specific.

Check: https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/mongodb/docs/current/reference/html/#change-streams